# Atomic open of non-existing file in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, concurrency

I want to write something to a file which name is in variable `$filename`.
I don't want to overwrite it, so I check first if it exists and then open it:

```
#stage1
if(-e $filename)
{
    print "file $filename exists, not overwriting\n";
    exit 1;
}

#stage2
open(OUTFILE, ">", $filename) or die $!;
```

But this is not atomic. Theoretically someone can create this file between `stage1` and `stage2`. Is there some variant of `open` command that will do these both things in atomic way, so it will fail to open a file for writing if the file exists?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an atomic way of opening files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);

my $filename = 'test';
my $fh;

# this is "atomic open" part
unless (sysopen($fh, $filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY)) {
    print "file $filename exists, not overwriting\n";
    exit 1;
}

# flock() isn't required for "atomic open" per se
# but useful in real world usage like log appending
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);

# use the handle as you wish
print $fh scalar localtime;
print $fh "\n";

# unlock & close
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
close $fh;
```

Debug session:

```
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~/stackoverflow$ cat test
Wed Dec 19 12:10:37 2012
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~/stackoverflow$ perl sysopen.pl 
file test exists, not overwriting
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~/stackoverflow$ cat test
Wed Dec 19 12:10:37 2012
```

Comment: If the flock is necessary, this doesn't answer the OP's question. Is it necessary, or does the sysopen do the trick?

Comment: Thank you @ikegami, I've edited the answer to point that `flock()` isn't related to the question, albeit usually present in the similar code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about multiple Perl scripts modifying the same file, just use the [flock()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) function in each one to lock the file you're interested in.

If you're worried about external processes, which you probably don't have control over, you can use the [sysopen()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) function. According to the *Programming Perl* book (which I highly recommend, by the way):

> To fix this problem of overwriting, you’ll need to use `sysopen`, which
>   provides individual controls over whether to create a new file or
>   clobber an existing one. And we’ll ditch that `–e` file existence test
>   since it serves no useful purpose here and only increases our exposure
>   to race conditions.

They also provide this sample block of code:

```
use Fcntl qw/O_WRONLY O_CREAT O_EXCL/;
open(FH, "<", $file)
    || sysopen(FH, $file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL)
    || die "can't create new file $file: $!";
```

In this example, they first pull in a few constants (to be used in the `sysopen` call). Next, they try to open the file with `open`, and if that fails, they then try `sysopen`. They continue on to say:

> Now even if the file somehow springs into existence between when open
>   fails and when `sysopen` tries to open a new file for writing, no harm
>   is done, because with the flags provided, `sysopen` will refuse to open
>   a file that already exists.

So, to make things clear for your situation, remove the file test completely (no more stage 1), and *only* do the open operation using code similar to the block above. Problem solved!

Comment: This still doesn't solve the *Theoretically someone can create this file between stage1 and stage2* issue! It's just a non-clobbering way of opening files.

Comment: Sure it does. We've completely gotten rid of "stage 1" from the OP's question. Now there's only one stage: the opening of the file!

Comment: Sorry to disagree... What about `open(FH, "<", $file) || (!sleep 1) || sysopen(...)`? There are still two stages, you just put them in the same statement. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, OK, saw your edit! So, why to use `open(FH, "<", $file)`, after all?

Comment: That's a good question. This code block comes right out of the Camel book, so I'm not sure why both would be needed. I guess the question is under what scenarios can the `open` fail and the `sysopen` succeed?

Comment: I believe that's because `O_EXCL` *may* do unexpected things in some scenarios, like NFS.

Comment: My friend says in his edition of the book there's no initial `open`, just the `sysopen` call. He's got a rather new edition. He also agrees with what creaktive says about old NFS (but I won't use NFS in my scenario).

Comment: FWIW, I pulled the code snippet above from the 4th edition of the book, which I believe is the latest (published in 2012, according to the title page).

Comment: Upon further inspection, I see that I have the first revision of the 4th edition (apparently some updates were made later in the year).